# Delay garbage collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, google-chrome, timeline

I'm using chrome (the dev version for my mac).

I was looking at the timeline for my page loading and I saw that there is a 150ms delay due to some garbage collection taking place while loading the page.

[image: loading times]

It's the yellow line.

I was curious if there's any way to stop this, delay it, whatever so I get the page to load faster?

Comment: 1/ It would help people answer you if you tagged your question with whatever language Chrome is developed in. 2/ Generally speaking, Garbage Collection is already triggered as late as possible, so you can only trigger it voluntarily early, not postpone it (unless you are willing to grow the heap).

Comment: I believe it's written in c++

Comment: Is the GC always triggered when you load the page? Which version of Chrome is it?

Answer (score 3):

Against the grain of some of the comments, this isn't a C++ issue.

Garbage Collection happens when v8 (the javascript engine in chrome) engine detects that it should start freeing up memory used by objects that are no longer needed in the code.  You can visit the [v8](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html#garb_coll) page for more information about what the garbage collector does.

There might be lots of reasons why your code is garbage collecting early, and in that case we would need to see your code.  Do you have a lot of variables that go out of scope at page load?

Answer (score -3):

Don't create so much garbage: Look at where your JavaScript program allocates memory during load and see if you can eliminate the garbage collection by reusing data structures or delaying that work until after the page has loaded. This lets you 'delay' garbage collection.